# Is there a way to see runs associated with a specific test plan in Azure Dev Ops test?

Tags: azure-devops

This may really be more a QA question. I'm sort of hamstrung in my organization, I don't have API access for some of the Azure REST calls. I've got a number of test plans with various suites, and reporting the overall current status in terms of passed, failed, etc. is straightforward.

What I'm not able to do easily is get a historical view of all the runs of a given test case. So I can't seem to easily get a metric that says (as an example) we had to run this test case 12 times before we got a pass. Most of the help I'm seeing online references some great ways to get all test IDs if you have API access, I'm not sure if there's another way outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is **New Test Plans Page** in azure devops **Previous Features**, which allows you to  view the historical test result of a test case.

First you need go to "**User setting**-->**Previous Features** of your azure devops and Turn on **New Test Plans Page**

[image]

Then Go to your **Test plan**-->Go to **Execute** page-->Click **3dot**-->Choose **View execution History**

[image]

Then you will see the historical test results in a new page. You can also filter the execution 
history as below highlighted

[image]